# Python: Each operand has a max of four digits in width. Otherwise, the error string returned will be: Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits

Tags: python, regex

I'll get a list which contains arithmetic operations. I have to check wether any number contains more than 4 digits.

`arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])`should pass.

`arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "38011 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])` should return an error.

Thats what how far I've come:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems):

if len(problems) > 5: 
   print("Error: Too many Problems.")
else:
   for problem in problems: 
      if "+" not in problem or "-" not in problem: 
          print("Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'.")
      elif re.search('[a-zA-Z]', problem):
          print("Error: Numbers must only contain digits.")
```

Comment: If you know regular expressions you can use them to find all sets of continuous digits in the strings. Then its easy to check length.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. Also, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Close! Post that as text in the question instead of an image and then we are good to go.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - We have code, vote to reopen?

Comment: This reopen is taking forever. Try: `re.search(r"\d{5,}", " ".join(problems)) is None`. This builds a single string with space separation then searches for any sequence of digits 5 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

**Five digits on end:**

```
\d{5}
[0-9]{5}
```

**Only integers with 5 or more digits:**

```js
(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)\d{5,}(?!\.?\d)
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{5,}                   digits (0-9) (at least 5 times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**Numbers with 5 or more digits in the integer part:**

```js
(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)\d{5,}(?!\d)
```

Same as above minus `\.?`.